# The intersection of two Sylow p-subgroups has the same order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and assume it has more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup.

It is known that order of intersection of two Sylow p-subgroups may change depending on the pairs of Sylow p-subgroups.

> I wonder whether there is a condition which guarantees that intersection of any two Sylow $p$-subgroups has the same order.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, if the Sylow subgroups have order a prime then all the intersections have one single element...

Comment: If the number of Sylow p-subgroups is at most 2...

Comment: number of the Sylow p-subgroup can not be 2.

Comment: But it can be 1. My above comment was kind of a joke of course, I guess you are looking for a deeper criterion.

Comment: Actually,it can not be 1 by my assumption :)thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I can prove the following, which provides a criterion to start with.

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a finite group. Then the following are equivalent.

$(a)$ For all $S,T \in Syl_p(G)$ with $S \neq T$, $S \cap T=1$.
$(b)$ For each non-trivial $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, $N_G(P)$ has a *unique* Sylow $p$-subgroup.
$(c)$ For each non-trivial $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, $P$ is contained in a *unique* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Nicky, I am sorry not give any response. I guess you found conditions for a Sylow subgroup to be T.I. subgroup. If you supply proofs, I would read.

Answer (score 2):

I have made up such a condition.

We know that the action of $G$ on $Syl_p(G)$ by conjugation is transitive. If this action is double transitive then the intersection of any two Sylow p-subgroups is conjugate and they must have same order.

Proof: Let $P,Q,R,S$ be elements of $Syl_p(G)$ such that $P\neq Q$ and $R\neq S$. By double transivity, $\exists x$ in $G$ such that $P^x=R$ and $Q^x=S$, thus $(P\cap Q)^x=P^x\cap Q^x =R\cap S$.

But I do not know when $G$ is double transive on $Syl_p(G)$. Should I ask it as a new question?

Comment: Did you ever find anything about when $G$ acts 2-transitively on its Sylow $p$-subgroups? There seems to be a fair amount of variety, but I guess it would be possible to give a classification of $G/R$ where $R$ is the intersection of normalizers of the Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Comment: Not something remarkable.But there are some groups which acts 2-transitively on its Sylow$p-$subgroup.I really expect interesting result about $G/R$.