# When is the action of $G$ on $\text{Syl}_p(G)$ by conjugation is double transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

We know that the action of $G$ on $\text{Syl}_p(G)$ by *conjugation* is transitive. I wonder when this action can be *double transitive* on  $\text{Syl}_p(G)$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Google for "action on sylow subgroups doubly transitive" - it throws up some very non-trivial papers. What exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569300/the-intersection-of-two-sylow-p-subgroups-has-the-same-order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ acts doubly transitively on its Sylow $p$-subgroups, and $K$ is the subgroup that normalizes all Sylow $p$-subgroups, then $G/K$ is isomorphic to a doubly transitive group in which the point stabilizer has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Finite doubly transitive groups have been classified. The examples with this property include ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, ${\rm PSU}(3,q)$, ${\rm Sz}(2^{2n+1})$ and $R(3^{2n+1})$ (Ree groups). There are also some affine examples - i.e. goups with a regular normal elementary abelian subgroup . For example the groups ${\rm AGL}(1,q)$ have this property for primes dividing $q-1$.

Comment: If I am wrong please correct me, by your defination $K=\cap{N_G(P)}$ for all $P$. And $G/K$ is acting $Syl_p(G)$

Comment: Yes that's right. You can't say much about $K$ in general,so it is better to try and describe the possibilities for $G/K$.

Comment: But I can not see why $Stab(G/K)$ has normal Sylow p-subgroup.Can you explain it?

Comment: We have a homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_n$ with kernel $K$, so ${\rm }im(\phi) \cong G/K$. The stabilizer of a point in ${\rm im}(\phi)$ is by definition of $\phi$ equal to the image of the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. So the stabilizer of a point in ${\rm im }(\phi)$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup.